# Pandas: going from long to wide format in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am having trouble going from a long format to a wide one, in pandas. There are plenty of examples going from wide to long, but I did not find one from long to wide.
I am trying to reformat my dataframe and pivot, groupby, unstack are a bit confusing for my use case.

This is how I want it to be. The numbers are actually the intensity column from the second image.
[image]

And this is how it is now

[image]

I tried to build a MultiIndex based on Peptide, Charge and Protein. Then I tried to pivot based on that multi index, and keep all the samples and their intensity as values:

```
df.set_index(['Peptide', 'Charge', 'Protein'], append=False)
df.pivot(index=df.index, columns='Sample', values='Intensity')
```

Of course, this does not work since my index is now a combination of the 3 and not an actual column in the dataframe.

It tells me

```
KeyError: None of [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3397898, step=1)] are in the [columns]
```

I tried also to group by, but I am not sure how to move from the long format back to wide. I am quite new to the dataframe way of thinking and I want to learn how to do this right.
It was very tempting for me to do an old school "java"-like approach with 4 for loops and building it as a matrix. Thank you in advnace!

Comment: Update your question with sample input data as text,  it's almost markup.  Also for desired layout.  images/pics cannot be used to demonstrate how to resolve your question

Comment: Consider pasting your data as text instead of taking a screenshot of them..

Answer (score 4):

I think based on your attempt that this might work:

```
df2 = df.pivot(['Peptide', 'Charge', 'Protein'], columns='Sample', values='Intensity').reset_index()
```

After that, if you want to remove the name from the column axis:

```
df2 = df2.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```